# Hello i am new to coding and i dont get what's wrong with the following script

Tags: python

I started coding this little password generator (with gui)using tkinter. When I got to the part where I actually had to add the generating function to the gui I ran into problems.
One of the main problems was the fact that when giving the button in the tkinter window the actual function the following error showed up "NameError: name 'convertor' is not defined".
I don't know how to fix it , if any of you are willing to help a new programmer I would appreciate that.
Here is the code:

```
    from tkinter import *
import random
wb = Tk()
wb.config(bg="#111116")
wb.geometry("300x300")
frame=Frame(height=200,width=200,bg="#111116")

frame.pack()
bt=Button(text="Generate",fg="white",bg="#111116",command=lambda : convertor())


bt.pack()

la=Label(frame,height=4,width=15,text="Your password here:")
la.grid(column=10,row=10)
entry1=Entry(wb,relief=SUNKEN,text="How long should the password be? ")
entry1.pack()

wb.mainloop()


def convertor(inter,pass_len,password,characters):
    characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    pass_len = int(entry1.get())
    inter=""

    password = ""

    for x in range(0, pass_len):
        inter = random.choice(characters)
        password = password + inter
    print(password)
convertor()
```

I thank you in advance to anyone willing to help a beginner out:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In the future, please start with your own research. I found that question by googling `python function is not defined`, although knowing what to google comes with experience :)

Comment: BTW, `convertor()` will fail because you're not passing in the necessary arguments (`inter,pass_len,password,characters`). Also `lambda: f()` can be switched to just `f`. This is called eta-reduction.